# How to get the file size pointed by a Windows shortcut under MinGW?

Tags: c, mingw, glib

I want to get the file size pointed by a Windows shortcut lnk file (not file-junction/symlink) under MinGW/GLib. The `g_stat` function in GLib tells me the size of a file or file-junction but not the size of the file pointed by an lnk file. Can anyone please help me here?

Answer (score 0):

You should be using `g_lstat` instead ([see here](http://www.gtk.org/api/2.6/glib/glib-File-Utilities.html#g-lstat))

Comment: g_lstat is no use for me here. I want the actual file's size, not the size of the link, which is what the use of g_lstat.

`The lstat() function is like stat() except that in the case of symbolic links, it returns information about the symbolic link itself and not the file that it refers to`